# Choosing a method for designing multilingual website

Tags: php, gettext, multilingual

I designed multilingual websites before and I used some `php` files for languages. for example:

**lang/en.php**

```
<?php
$_l['HELLO'] = "Hello";
$_l['BYE'] = "Bye";
?>
```

**lang/fr.php**

```
<?php
$_l['HELLO'] = "Bonjour";
$_l['BYE'] = "au revoir";
?>
```

and then use `$__l` array in my code.

Now I want to know is it optimal? On some sites I read that I should use `gettext`, is it the best way? or is there another methods?

I do not know which way is best and what is the right way?

Comment: Use database for this. It's much maintainable, easier and you have more control

Comment: Is database optimize ? because I should send a query to database for each string.

Comment: You can use some kind of caching for this, if you do not expect for example, your translations to be updated more often than once in an hour, set the cache to clear in an hour

Comment: @RoyalBg Thank you, did you mean `memcache` or `apc` or somthing like this for caching ?

Comment: Yes, that was my point :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no one best method. I've read about gettext lately and sometimes there are problems on hosting accounts with using it. So your method is probably one of the best because it does not need any queries to database each time you need translation.

Comment: database could be cached, so there is no excuse to use the file system for this, it makes in completely unmaintainable and will require complicated tools, if one want to give access to someone to translate strings

Comment: Yes, of course in more complex application data could be in database or other files but I saw some applications that for generating one site do multiple queries to database to get many translations instead of caching them